# Getting real-time stock market data in one file

Tags: market-data

There are lots of services which provide stock market data on ticket-by-ticker basis, so to get the 1-min data for each US stock I will need to perform a few thousand requests each minute. Is there any service which provides something like a single CSV file updated every 1/5/15/60 mins with the data of all NYSE/NASDAQ stocks?

Comment: Would alphavantage suit you? https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/ I don't know whether the data is then already aggregated into 1min intervals, though...

Comment: Nope, Alpha Vantage only provides a ticker-by-ticker API, and given that their free rate limit is 5 req/min & their best tariff allows 1200 req/min — it's actually impossible to grab real-time / 1-min candles for all US stocks with their API

Comment: Sorry, yes - I did not read your *bulk* download requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Algoseek is the source, interval aggregations available for bulk snapshots. Hope it helps.

Many Others can provide this as well, request a timely flat file snapshot. That kind of data can get pricey; not sure how much of a factor that is to you. Xignite is another source capable of generating such flat files for you.

Comment: Yes, they seem to provide bulk exports, but they happen to be more expensive than doing a few thousands requests each minute to grab all the data from some other providers. I was hoping for the opposite...